# Как повернуть View без артефактов

Tags: android, view, rotation

У меня есть самое обычной View с бекграундом. Я устанавливаю свойство `android:rotation="-8"` для наклона.[image: Повернутое View]

Как видно края у такого View не сглаженные. Можно ли сделать их ровными?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Видно, что система пытается сглаживать. Все зависит от масштаба картинки которую вы представили и от типа backgtound.

Comment: Это не картинка, просто background с цветом